# Are interfaces in C# inherited or Implemented

Tags: c#

I have a simple question in C#

**Are Interfaces inherited or are they implemented?**

Thanks

Comment: I would start reading here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11155/Abstract-Class-versus-Interface It's a gives a good explanation of both interfaces and abstract classes :)

Comment: A class can *implement* as many interfaces as you want. You can however, have interfaces that *inherit* from base interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes implement interfaces. Abstract classes are being inherited. A class can inherit from one class, but implement as many interfaces as you want it to.

However, interfaces can also "inherit" other interfaces. They don't really implement them, so it's more like inheriting their interface contracts, but they can implement multiple interfaces, so it's not really inheritance either. A class that will implement an interface which inherits from other interfaces, will have to implement all interface contracts that are included in the original interface, and it's base interfaces as well, recursively.

You should also read about [abstract classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx), for more useful information on the general subject.

Answer (score 0):

That's just terminology. According to [one MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) and [another one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx) a class or struct **implements** an interface. However, when you declare a new interface, that interface may **inherit** from other base interfaces.

Comment: Interfaces have to inherit, because they don't add any implemention to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You implement an interface by using a class. It is implemented, because it has no definition. Once you have a class. Be it abstract or a normal class, you inherit, because you are inheriting pre-built functionality.

Although there is 2 caveats.

1. abstract classes don't have to add any implementation to their methods (throwing exceptions is acceptable, or even leaving them empty, or marking the methods and properties as abstract to show the implementation is incomplete. Empty implementations are legitimate as long as the return type is satisfied. They just have to define the methods used by the interface.
2. you inherit from other classes, but adding 'sealed' to the class name will stop any one else from inheriting it e.g. System.String and System.Type

Answer (score 0):

that depends if the thing 'using' the interface is a class or another interface.

A class implements the interface (and any interfaces that it inherits).

Another interface inherits (or extends) an interface

Answer (score 0):

- Classes can implement one / more interfaces implicitly and/or
  explicitly.
- An interface can inherit other interfaces.
- The implicit implemented methods of an Interface can be abstract / virtual can be
  overriden in derived classes.

In short **Interfaces are implemented and implementation of the interfaces can be inherited**